# Simplify JavaScript list of objects with rows of varying dynamic fields

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript list of objects with rows of varying dynamic fields that I wish to simply.
For an input list:

```
{ A: a1, B: "b1" },
{ A: a2, B: "b2" },
{ C: c1, D: "d1" },
{ C: c2, D: "d2" }
```

I wish the output list to be:

```
{ A: a1, B: "b1", C: c1, D: "d1"},
{ A: a2, B: "b2", C: c2, D: "d2"}
```

where A,B, C & D are dynamic fields at runtime

I've explored using .reduce & .map but could use some assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+object+array+dynamically+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What is a `list of objects`? An object array? If so, show it as such

Comment: Could you specify how `{ A: a1, B: "b1" }` gets matched with `{ C: c1, D: "d1" }` and `{ A: a2, B: "b2" }` gets matched with `{ C: c2, D: "d2" }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added more to test what happened when more than 2 of the same key

It is more verbose than [the answer I voted up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652844/295783), but it does only loop once.

```js
const groups = data.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  const curKeys = Object.keys(cur);
  if (i === 0) { // first time. This can be shortened but makes it harder to read
    curKeys.forEach(key => acc.keys[key] = 0);
    acc.result.push(cur);
    return acc;
  }
  Object.entries(cur).forEach((entry) => { // loop each entry
    const [key, val] = entry;
    let idx = acc.keys[key];
    if ((idx ?? undefined) === undefined) { // do we have a key stored?
      acc.keys[key] = 0;
      idx = 0;
    } else {
      acc.keys[key] = ++idx; // increase the index of the found letter
      if (idx > acc.result.length) acc.result.push({});
    }
    acc.result[idx] = { ...acc.result[idx], ...({ [key]: val }) };
  })
  return acc;

}, { keys: {}, result: [] })["result"];

console.log(groups)
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      A: "a1",
      B: "b1"
    },
    {
      A: "a2",
      B: "b2"
    },
    {
      C: "c1",
      D: "d1"
    },
    {
      C: "c2",
      D: "d2"
    },
    {
      C: "c3",
      D: "d3"
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```js
const data = [
  { A: "a1", B: "b1" },
  { A: "a2", B: "b2" },
  { C: "c1", D: "d1" },
  { C: "c2", D: "d2" }
];

const resultObject = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
    const value = item[key];
    const numberValue = value.slice(1);
    resultObject[numberValue] = {...resultObject[numberValue], [key]: value};
  });
});

const resultArray = Object.values(resultObject).map((value) => value);
console.log(resultArray);
```

1. Loop through the data items.
2. Get key and value of each item.
3. Get the number from the value (by ignoring the letter).
4. Add the key, value pair to the resultObject with the number key.
5. Convert the object to the desired output.